# How to test Grails webflow with input parameter?

Tags: spring, testing, grails, spring-webflow

I'm in the process of writing tests for webflows and I have a webflow (A) that calls another webflow (sub-webflow) (B) during its execution. If A calls B it always states a required parameter / input with the call. Testing A alone is not a problem but how can I test B on it's own? The input parameter is states as:

```
input {
    station(required: true)
}
```

I tried starting with startFlow() but that gives me the following exception:

```
Failure: testCreateWizardSubSubFlow(com.lstelcom.spectraweb.data.EquipmentFlowTests)
org.springframework.webflow.engine.FlowInputMappingException: 
Errors occurred during input mapping on startup of the 'createWizardSubSub' flow;
    errors = [[RequiredError@51a9e7fc mapping = station -> station, code = 'required', error = true, errorCause = [null], originalValue = [null], mappedValue = [null]]]    
at grails.test.WebFlowTestCase.startFlow(WebFlowTestCase.groovy:130)
at com.lstelcom.spectraweb.data.EquipmentFlowTests.testCreateWizardSubSubFlow(EquipmentFlowTests.groovy:38)
```

A method call of startFlow with an input parameter (e.g., startFlow(new Station()) ) does not exist in `WebFlowTestCase` as I get the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.lstelcom.spectraweb.data.EquipmentFlowTests.startFlow() is applicable for argument types: (com.lstelcom.spectraweb.data.stations.Station) values: []
Possible solutions: getFlow(), getFlow()
    at com.lstelcom.spectraweb.data.EquipmentFlowTests.testCreateWizardSubSubFlow(EquipmentFlowTests.groovy:38)
```

So the question is how can I test a webflow with input parameter?

Comment: DId you ever figure out what was the problem here ? I am facing the same issue.